# Delete rows from multiple tables in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I delete from multiple tables if all tables have common value
here used code but doesn't work

```
 <?php

include_once("config.php");

$order_no = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $order_date = $_REQUEST['date'];


$conn->query("DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `date`='$order_date' and `order_no`='$order_no';
DELETE FROM `customer_order` WHERE `order_date`='$order_date' and `order_no`='$order_no';
DELETE FROM `driver_order` WHERE `order_date`='$order_date' and `order_no`='$order_no';");
header('location:index.php');

?>
```

Comment: you're obviously trying to run a multi query

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$date` variable but use `$order_date` in your query.

Please note this is not safe way of doing it. Look for SQL Injection.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work. It doesn't delete the records or it's failing with the error. If you provide a date as a date only (ie. 2016-12-06) you can change your queries to: `WHERE DATE(order_date) = DATE('$order_date')` to compare only the date part not the time.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
<?php

 include_once("config.php");

    $order_no = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $order_date = $_REQUEST['date'];


 $conn->query("DELETE `orders`,`customer_order`,`driver_order` 
 FROM `orders`,`customer_order`,`driver_order`
  WHERE `orders`.`date`='$order_date' and `orders`.`order_no`='$order_no' AND
`customer_order`.`order_date`='$order_date' and `customer_order`.`order_no`='$order_no' AND
```

`driver_order`.`order_date`='$order_date' 
     and `driver_order`.`order_no`='$order_no';");
      header('location:index.php');

```
     ?>
```